# Android common super class for Activity and FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, extends, inheritance

I want to create a generic super class called **Vista** that extends android Activity, and then create all my activities extending my class Vista (thus to inherit all my common methods in all my activities). But in the project I have some FragmentActivity classes and I can't extend these from the class Vista.

Any solution? 
Can i  change my FragmentActivity in a simile Activity and use android.app.fragment  with TabHost inside, instead of android.support.v4.fragment because I am develop for android 4+ ?

[image]

Comment: Just make `Vista` extend `FragmentActivity` and nothing else in your code should change. Why wouldn't you want to do that?

Comment: I want to do that because I am doing a complex project and have a lot of common methods in my activities. Also, I want to maintain order in the classes using a clear hierarchy for simple reading and to make easy any future code upgrade

Comment: Wait, I did give out an answer, just change `Vista` from extending `Activity` to be extending `FragmentActivity` that would solve the issue and would not require any changes done to any of your `MyActivity1`, `MyActivity2`, and `MyAcitivty3`. This is the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the *Vista* class a standalone helper class. Then create an *ActivityVista* class that extends *Activity* and includes an instance of the *Vista* helper class as a private member. And also create a *FragmentActivityVista* class that extends *FragmentActivity* and includes an instance of the *Vista* helper class.

The *ActivityVista* and *FragmentActivityVista* classes will have to have a bunch of forwarding functions that call through to the *Vista* helper class, but they at least won't have to duplicate the full functionality.

Comment: Like a candy :) Was doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: This is the mix-in pattern.  There are some packages for this that use annotations to automate creating the forwarding functions: http://berniesumption.com/software/mixins-for-java/

Comment: In my case a standalone helper class is not a very good solution because a lot of common methods use android Activity methods

Comment: @lory105 When you construct the `Vista` class, just pass it a reference to the containing `Activity` class. That way whenever it needs to call an `Activity` method in can just use that reference.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways :

1. Add VistaFragmentActivity and extend it for Fragments
2. Make yout Vista to extend FragmentActivity

Best wishes.